# Getting Stream from System.Windows.Input.Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I get the Stream of the cursor defined inside `System.Windows.Input.Cursor`?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't.  Neither the .NET Framework nor the OS has an encoder for the .cur and .ani file format.  The latter being the bigger hangup.  Belongs in a programming tool, like VS.  Nobody can propose an alternative when you don't explain why you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot. After reviewing the MSDN, the stream is part of the constructor and not accessible afterward most likely making it a private property.

In all my years, I cannot say that I have ever used the "Cursor" constructor like that either, but I guess if you had to pass a customized mouse cursor that is how you would do it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx

What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried(purely out of my own curiosity)?